# how can I disable console.info messages temporarily in chrome?

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome, logging, console

I have a lot of console messages for my app during development, is there a way to turn these off and on without having to comment them all out one by one?

If possible, with a variable to switch between the modes, perhaps even during runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most browsers have filtering by level  built into the console; Here's an example using Chrome

[image: Warning level]

Answer (score -1):

I wrote this little hack to be able to switch it on and off (do so by changing the window.loggingInfoDisabled variable with your code). This can also be done for .log, .warning and .error of course.

//To be able to turn off the logging of info messages
    window.loggingInfoDisabled = true;

```
window.console.info_old = window.console.info;
window.console.info = function(myString) {
    if (window.loggingInfoDisabled) {
        //do nothing
    }
    else {
        console.info_old(myString);        
    }
}
```